# how to load multiple URL in android using visual studio c#

Tags: c#, android, url, load, infinite

I am a developing an application (apk) it is nothing but a display of stored images & bitmap images (url).This is my first application & I am using code by watching different tutorials that i need to code over youtube and searching websites to get help. 
Below here is the whole code for application.

```
namespace androidapk
{
    [Activity(Label = "android", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]

    public class Activity : Android.App.Activity
    {
        private ImageView ImageContainer;
       // private ImageView UrlContainer;
        private int CurrentImage = 0;
     //   private int CurrentUrl = 0;
        private Button nextClick;
        private Button backClick;
        int[] images = { Resource.Drawable.orange, Resource.Drawable.Icon, Resource.Drawable.images02, Resource.Drawable.buttonarrow, Resource.Drawable.images };
      //  string[] Urls = { "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiFsZgrhpFIx496REDS7XimTQVo07W6zFwULlNFIO3OpgPNCMc,https://www.google.com.pk/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fupload%2Fwater_PNG3290.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fpngimg.com%2Fimg%2Fnature%2Fwater&docid=egiWzVBWw_5-bM&tbnid=geXqbWHLhH-PPM%3A&w=1280&h=798&bih=667&biw=1366&ved=0ahUKEwitguqNm8POAhWHWhQKHc_TBewQMwgxKAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8" };



        public Action<object, EventArgs> Click { get; private set; }
        public int FindViewByIddemoImageview { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);       
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            nextClick = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Btnup);
            backClick = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.Btnback);
            ImageContainer = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.demoImageView);
           // UrlContainer = (ImageView)FindViewById();


            //Android.Net.Uri url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiFsZgrhpFIx496REDS7XimTQVo07W6zFwULlNFIO3OpgPNCMc");

           var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiFsZgrhpFIx496REDS7XimTQVo07W6zFwULlNFIO3OpgPNCMc");

            RunOnUiThread(() => ImageContainer.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap));

            nextClick.Click += delegate {
                 NextImagePic();
          //      NextImageUrl();
            };

            backClick.Click += delegate {
                BackImagePic();
            };
         //HapticFeedbackConstants
        }

        private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
        {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }

            return imageBitmap;
        }

        private void NextImagePic()
        {
            if (CurrentImage == 0)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => ImageContainer.SetImageResource(images[CurrentImage + 1]));
                CurrentImage++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (CurrentImage < images.Count() - 1)
                {
                    CurrentImage++;
                    RunOnUiThread(() => ImageContainer.SetImageResource(images[CurrentImage]));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "This is last image.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
        }
        private void BackImagePic()
        {
            if (CurrentImage == 0)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => ImageContainer.SetImageResource(images[CurrentImage]));
                Toast.MakeText(this, "This is first image.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentImage--;
                RunOnUiThread(() => ImageContainer.SetImageResource(images[CurrentImage]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i have displayed successfully images stored using arrays [] but i want to display multiple images in arrays using URL's I have displayed single image using single URL.

Comment: If you can display a single image from the URL you have 3/4 of the work done, just do the same as amny times as you need. This: `var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("http://image.url.png");` is where the "magic" happens.

Comment: i have displayed images using arrays & i want to do same for the URL using list of URL or Arrays of String in which i can add many URL's according to application's need.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, do you want to create a list of URL's? If that's it use `List<string> UrlList` and use the method `Add` to add as many URL's as needed, to acces each URL you have to do this: `UrlList[index]`.